# Why JS/Jquery does not seem to work in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

For some reason my Jquery script won't work on IE7. It does however work in all other browsers. I have read somewhere that IE7 is very picky on commas and such, but I can't figure out what I have done wrong here. Any clues?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad");

var paddingLeft = ($(window).width() - 820) / 2;
var paddingRight = ($(window).width() - 820) / 2;

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )
{
    $(window).resize(function() 
    {
        paddingLeft = ($(window).width() - 820) / 2;
        $('.block_bouw').css('padding-left', paddingLeft);

        paddingRight = ($(window).width() - 820) / 2;
        $('.block_industrie').css('padding-right', paddingRight);
    });

    $('.block_bouw').css('padding-left', paddingLeft);  
    $('.block_bouw').delay(0).animate({ 
            marginLeft: '0',
        }, 0, function() {

    });
    $('.block_bouw').click(function(){
        window.location = 'bouw';
    });

    $('.block_industrie').css('padding-right', paddingRight);   
    $('.block_industrie').delay(0).animate({
            right: '0',
        }, 0, function(){

    });
    $('.block_industrie').click(function(){
        window.location = 'industrie';
    });
}

else {
    $(window).resize(function() 
    {
        paddingLeft = ($(window).width() - 820) / 2;
        $('.block_bouw').css('padding-left', paddingLeft);

        paddingRight = ($(window).width() - 820) / 2;
        $('.block_industrie').css('padding-right', paddingRight);
    });

    $('.block_bouw').css('padding-left', paddingLeft);  
    $('.block_bouw').delay(500).animate({ 
            marginLeft: '0',
        }, 2000, function() {

    });
    $('.block_bouw').click(function(){
        window.location = 'bouw';
    });

    $('.block_industrie').css('padding-right', paddingRight);   
    $('.block_industrie').delay(500).animate({
            right: '0',
        }, 2000, function(){

    });
    $('.block_industrie').click(function(){
        window.location = 'industrie';
    });
}

$(".product.module .item").css("margin-right","27px");
$(".product.module .item:nth-child(3n)").css("margin-right", "0px");

$(".project.module .item").css("margin-left","26px");
$(".project.module .item:nth-child(3n)").css("margin-left", "0px");


$('.popout', this).hide();

$('.pin').hover(function(){
    //var h = $('.popout', this).outerHeight() * -1;
    var id = (this.id);
    $('.popout').css("margin-top", ($('.popout',this).outerHeight()*-1)+14 );
    $('.popout', this).show(100);
    $('.option' + "#" + id).addClass('hover');
},function(){
    $('.popout', this).hide(100);
    $('.option').removeClass('hover');
});

$('.option').hover(function(){
    var idoption = (this.id);
    $('.popout').css("margin-top", ($('.popout' + "#" + idoption).outerHeight()*-1)+14 );
    $('.popout' + "#" + idoption).stop().show(100);
},function(){
    $('.popout').hide(100);
});
});
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the javascript console?

Comment: Any errors? Incorrect behaviour...?

Comment: Why are you browser-detecting???

Comment: Where is this resource (html/js) located? IE considers javascript on thelocal disk are unsafe and won't load them

Comment: Doing that much DOM work in a "resize" handler is a really, really bad idea.  Browsers fire "resize" very rapidly while the window is being resized. To avoid bogging down the browser completely, you need to involve a timer to prevent doing work beyond a certain number of times per second.

Comment: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
petson.js, line 22 character 4

Comment: @Mitchel Jager Inside of all of your `animate` calls you have a trailing comma on the objects without additional fields, I would recommend removing these.

Comment: Also, stop calling `$(window).width()` redundantly - call it once and save the result.

Comment: @MitchelJager Which line is 22?

Comment: It's fixed Tim Down had the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspected, the problem is that you have some trailing commas here that mess up in old IE. The offending lines are

```
marginLeft: '0',
```

and

```
right: '0',
```

... twice each.

Here's a site I found via a quick web search that finds trailing commas in JavaScript code. It seems to work.

http://trailingcomma.com/